# How do I check if user 'IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolName' exists in powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to automate some DB configuration for my developers.  For development and testing, we're just using the ApplicationPoolIdentity service accounts (one of our test servers hates NETWORK SERVICE so that's not an option), so I need to configure databases to automatically grant permissions to the correct account for IIS.  But developers are often only running the database script, not the database and web scripts.

Because of that, the IIS AppPool may not exist at the time they're running the DB script, which means that by extension the IIS AppPool\myAppPoolName user will not exist either.  So when I attempt to grant them access to the local SQL database, they get an error.

So the question is, how do I check that these IIS AppPool service accounts exist in Powershell?  I know how to confirm the existence of AD users, or local users, but these IIS apppool service accounts are in neither list.  Where do they live?  Is it a listing not accessible from Powershell?

I can do something dumb like just catching and handling the error during the permissions step, but I'd rather ask permission than forgiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the IIS application pool identity's permission account is IIS AppPool\myAppPoolName. If we want to check this account is exists or not. We just need to check the myAppPoolName is exists or not.

To achieve this, I suggest you could refer to below powershell command to check the application pool is exists or not.

Command:

```
import-module webadministration

$AppPoolName="Test"

if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$AppPoolName)
{
"AppPool is already there"
return $true;
}
else
{
return $false;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This fails if the app pool is not using the AppPoolIdentity.  It will create a false positive that the username exists.  More work would have to be done - checking the AppPool IdentityType to ensure it's 4.

It's doable, I was hoping for some single magic method that returns the list, but this approach is doable.

Answer (score 0):

AppPool identity is a virtual account that it will not show up as a user in the Windows User Management Console. This docs maybe helpful: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). Also this (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/)

Comment: Those links explain what the IIS AppPool\useraccount things are, which I was already aware of.  They don't offer any information about how to get a list of them.

I suppose the only real option would be to iterate across the list of AppPools and check the ones that are using an AppPoolIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've taken a forgiveness-not-permission here.  I attempt to create the SQL login and corresponding users and handle the exception if they can't.

Edit:

This seems to be the best way to get the actual list of them:

```
$appPoolIdentities = Get-IISAppPool |
   Where-Object {$_.ProcessModel.IdentityType -eq 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'} |
   ForEach-Object {"IIS AppPool\$($_.Name)"}
```